# Initializing a struct using a macro

Tags: c, macros, struct

I've been searching and can't find anything. Consider this structure

```
typedef struct student
{
    char name[40];
    char grade;
}Student;
```

how do I make a macro for initializing a structure with parameters? Something along the lines of

```
Student John = STUDENT(John, A);
```

where STUDENT is a defined macro

Comment: Why would you use a macro? You could also simply use a function to initialize a `Student`.

Comment: Because i was told to do it that way

Comment: Well ok, however I find this a bit surprising.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define STUDENT(name, grade) { #name, grade }
```

Then `Student John = STUDENT(John, 'A');` would be expanded into

```
Student John = { "John", 'A' };
```

Comment: This works thanks, but can you explain why or where can i read to why this works?

Comment: It'd be better style to require the code to have `STUDENT("John", 'A')`

Comment: @dimitrov.l you mean why you can initialise structure with `={}`, or how macro expanded to that line?

Comment: @keltar, here i am again, whenever i try to create a second "student" i get errors, your solution works but only if i want to initialize one student

Comment: It works for initialisation, not assignment (e.g. not `Student John; John = STUDENT(John, 'A');`). Structure assignment is allowed only in C99 or later, as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char name[40];
    char grade;
}Student;

#define STUDENT(name, grade) (Student){ #name, *#grade }

int main(){
    Student John = STUDENT(John, A); 

    printf("%s, %c\n", John.name, John.grade);
    return 0;
}
```